# Get mouse direction relative to x y coordinates

Tags: java, game-physics, direction

I am working on a java game, in which I want to implement some combat. the way I want to implement the combat is through a single button, and depending on where the mouse cursor is, I want to attack in that direction. The problem is, i can't detect the direction relative to the player with just the x and y coordinates. if i did this without any math or anything else, i would get these kind of quadrants to measure directions from:
[image: Cross format]

^^ These wouldn't work because that would get me: up-left, up-right, down-left, and down-right.

I want instead have up, down, left, and right, like this: [image: X format] where if the mouse is in one of these quadrants, it would attack in that direction. this would get me up, right, down, left (following the quadrants shown above)

Heres the information I have: Mouse x coordinate, Mouse Y coordinate, player X coordinate, player Y coordinate.

Im sure there is some math to convert these quadrants [image: Cross format of collision detecting] into these quadrants [image: X format] so that I can detect which direction the mouse is, relative to the player.

Here is an example of the code I would use to detect the mouse direction (this code is for the [image: Cross format] format, because I cant figure out the other one):

```
private Direction getMouseRelativeDirection() {
    if(mouseX > x && mouseY < y)
        return Direction.topRight;
    if(mouseX > x && mouseY > y)
        return Direction.bottomRight;
    if(mouseX < x && mouseY < y)
        return Direction.topLeft;
    if(mouseX < x && mouseY > y)
        return Direction.bottomLeft;

//to prevent errors if the mouse isn't in a quadrant, just return null
    return null;
}
```

I hope I gave enough information for someone to figure out the direction math, but let me know if you need more info!

EDIT:

I fixed this with some searching on google and troubleshooting of my own.. turns out using lines formulas to get each line relative to the mouse is the way to go.

Comment: one way: `dx > abs(dy)` it is in +x direction (right); `dx < -abs(dy)` it is in -x direction (left); similar for y direction. Or calculate angle `atan2(dy, dx)` and check the different sectors (e.g. between `PI/4` and `-PI/4` is +x)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help you calculate the angle between the two points.

```
double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(mouseY - y, mouseX - x));
if(angle < 0) { angle += 360; } // angle always >= 0
```